# Can't run a python file in a detached screen

Tags: screen

I am trying to run several python files in screens, starting the screens within a for loop in bash. The screens should not start attached so that the for loop can continue without the python file needing to be finished. I've found online, e.g. through [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/983176/1663550) that something like `screen -dmS "python3 test.py"` should work; however, all this does for me is create the screen with the name "python3 test.py", and when I attach the screen I can see that nothing is running.

test.py is a file I created which contains

```
import time
time.sleep(10000)
```

the real script I want to use is an ML file so I could also see this was not working as intended as my GPU ended up with no jobs on it.

Could someone please explain why this is not working -- I have tried this both on my Linux (ubuntu) machine and Mac, both do the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`-S` is the flag for session name ([man 1 screen](https://linux.die.net/man/1/screen)).

You can run your script detached with `screen -S test -dm python3 test.py`.

Edit: the command and parameter don't need to be put in a string.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. When I do this, and then use `screen -ls` I get the following (on Mac) `No Sockets found in /var/folders/yv/hw3hqmj96qvb_00p3593pc1c0000gn/T/.screen.`, and when on Linux `No Sockets found in /run/screen/S-irelan_d.`.

Comment: @DavidIreland I just tried `screen -S test -dm python3 -c 'import time; time.sleep(5)'` and it works as expected.

Comment: Thanks @ljmc. I just tried this, and it has also worked for me. Any idea what is going wrong in the original command?

Comment: @DavidIreland From the man page, `screen [ -options ] [ cmd [ args ] ]`, putting the command and args in a string must not be allowed.

Comment: @lmjc is there a workaround for this then? What I will need to do eventually is first activate a conda environment and then run the Python file. Could I not do something like `screen -S test -dm bash -c 'conda activate env_name; python3 test.py'`?

Comment: Yes, that's a very common way to work around running several commands in one shot. You might want to use `&&` rather than `;` to make sure your first command runs successfully.

Comment: @lmjc many thanks, I just tried this and it worked!